# Is it possible to scale the whole view of an app?

Tags: ios, swift, transformation, ibaction, cgaffinetransform

so I've been working on this project that involves the whole app's view to be flipped by scaling( if its even possible). I've done this before with a label but I have no idea where to start with the whole app.

I plan on pressing a button and then the whole screen flips by scaling.

here is my attempt:

```
@IBAction func Flip(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,animations: {
        self.UIView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

As I said, I dont know where to start, but I was just wondering if it was even possible to have a whole app just flip and if so, is there any way I could get through this problem.

About Duplicate: My Previous question (that was marked as a duplicate) talks about MapBox, and how I can change the Turn-by-Turn UI, but I thought it was better off knowing how to flip the whole app because adding Navigation and Mapbox to the situation makes it a whole different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UIWindow` inherits from `UIView`, you might be able to just apply a transform to it:

```
// Assuming your AppDelegate has a "window" property.
UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```